# Post an item to TPL action block with Task.run and without

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I'm new to TPL library and have a simple question that I didn't find an answer for.

what the difference(if there any at all) between calling a TPL block like this:

```
foreach (var t in paramsLisr)
{
  someBlock.Post(t);
}
```

vs

```
foreach (var t in paramsLisr)
{
 Task.run(()={someBlock.Post(t)});                        
}
```

Comment: This will helps you.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example is completely redundant and bordering on wrong. There is no point starting a task to post to an action block.

`ActionBlock` and alike, use an internal buffer and will seamlessly consume messages (unless you have set the `BoundedCapacity`). Even if you have set `BoundedCapacity` using a `Task` to post will be the wrong approach, and you should probably use another block to buffer the messages

Comment: Thanks for the clarification,
does this code is also a bad approach?

'code'

                    Parallel.ForEach(collection, t => {

                        someBlock.Post(t);
                    });

Comment: @Zlex it depends what you are doing, the fact you are using a TPL ForEach says that what ever you are doing should probably be already part of the pipeline. I am not saying there isnt any cases far tasks and threads to post to a Block, however as it stands i see no reason in the information you have supplied. Why would you need to do this?

Comment: right now for nothing, I'm just trying to understand the TPL library and what wrong and what is right before I'm doing anything 
right now I just have 2 blocks that linked to each other and my BoundedCapacity is 10,
in the the future i would like to get 100 images and process 10 in each time(in the first block) and i dont want to wait to  the TPL 2nd block to end to post the next mission

Comment: `BoundedCapacity` is not what you want, you want, `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`